# Google apps script setting dates incorrectly

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

When setting the values of cells using Google Apps Scripts, dates are being formatted incorrectly.

As an example the object I am passing back to be updated is: "4/23/2019"

However when it is set, the value is shown as "/OADate(43639)/"

I am using the following batch update to set the values

```
Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate(resource, spreadsheetId);
```

Does anyone know how to get around this?

Comment: Check the default locale for your spreadsheets https://support.google.com/docs/answer/58515?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en  It may affect the date and number formatitng

Comment: Can you provide ``resource``? If you are using ``userEnteredValue``, the document says ``Note: Dates, Times and DateTimes are represented as doubles in serial number format.``. If I misunderstood your request body, I apologize.

Comment: Ahh, thank you, i've noticed that for some reason my date is being converted to an OADate, can you give an example of what format it needs to be in as in the serial number format?

Comment: I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was down to the date being converted somewhere along the line by a third party component to an OADate.

I used the following function to convert the date to a serial date which then worked.

```
function fromOADate(oadate) {
    var date = new Date(((oadate - 25569) * 86400000));
    var tz = date.getTimezoneOffset();
    return new Date(((oadate - 25569 + (tz / (60 * 24))) * 86400000));
}
```